# How to find out Exact Match using CEM Package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find the Exact Match in my dataset using the CEM library in R. Here is my dataset given.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y_ZN_FW163R6ZpYRuDyOtUbKtSakgr-IBhpg-rZQQC8/edit?usp=sharing

I am using the following code but I am getting an error while running CEM function to find out the exact match.

```
    ##loading CEM Package for Exact Matching
require(cem)

Dataset_Patient <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE) ## Loading Dataset

Le <- data.frame(na.omit(Dataset_Patient)) ## Converting Dataset into Dataframe

str(Le) ## Check the Structure of Dataset as Variables

tr <- which(Le$TXA==0) ## Grouping the dataset according to TXA No / Yes 
ct <- which(Le$TXA==1)
ntr <- length(tr)
nct <- length(ct)

## Calculate Mean to find out the difference 
mean(Le$TXA[tr]) - mean(Le$TXA[ct])
mean(Le$Sex[tr]) - mean(Le$Sex[ct])
mean(Le$Age[tr]) - mean(Le$Age[ct])
mean(Le$HTN[tr]) - mean(Le$HTN[ct])
mean(Le$Pulmonary.HTN[tr]) - mean(Le$Pulmonary.HTN[ct])
mean(Le$Airway.diseases[tr]) - mean(Le$Airway.diseases[ct])
mean(Le$Malignancy[tr]) - mean(Le$Malignancy[ct])
mean(Le$Bleeding.disorders[tr]) - mean(Le$Bleeding.disorders[ct])
mean(Le$On.anticoagulants_antiplatelets[tr]) - mean(Le$On.anticoagulants_antiplatelets[ct])
mean(Le$Required.ICU.admission[tr]) - mean(Le$Required.ICU.admission[ct])
mean(Le$Classification.of.hemoptysis[tr]) - mean(Le$Classification.of.hemoptysis[ct])
mean(Le$Respiratory.support.[tr]) - mean(Le$Respiratory.support.[ct])

## selection of Columns in the Dataset for CEM Analysis and Matching 
vars <- c("Sex", "Age", "Smooking", "HTN", "Pulmonary.HTN", "Airway.diseases", "Malignancy", "Bleeding.disorders", "On.anticoagulants_antiplatelets", "Required.ICU.admission","Classification.of.hemoptysis","Respiratory.support.")

imbalance(group=Le$TXA, data=Le[vars])

todrop <- c("TXA", "Age")
imbalance(group=Le$TXA, data=Le[vars], drop=todrop)

mat <- cem(treatment = "treated", data = Le, keep.all=TRUE)
mat
```

Please check the code and help me where I am making mistake. Immediate response highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Given the code that you've shared, there is no variable called `treated` in the dataset, so I used `TXA` in place of `treated` in the call to `cem()`.  You're getting an error because it's not finding any matches. At the stage where it identifies the matched cases, there are none, so it returns a long string of `NA` values.  When the function tries to use these to identify observations, it throws an error.

Comment: Hi, bro @DaveArmstrong, I have tested it using TXA variable as well. The treated variable is not part of this dataset. I am getting following error.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong  

Error in `[.default`(tmp, x, bg) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In reduce.var(data[[i]], cutpoints[[vnames[i]]]) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is almost no data at high levels of `SOFA.score`.  Here's the table of `SOFA.score` by `TXA`.

```
#     0  1
# 0  53  2
# 1  63  0
# 2  66  1
# 3  20  0
# 4  22  1
# 5  27  1
# 6  21  2
# 7  16  0
# 8  10  0
# 9  12  0
# 10  8  1
# 11  5  1
# 12  4  1
# 13  2  0
# 14  1  0
# 15  1  0
# 16  1  0
# 19  0  1
```

If you change the default cutpoints for `SOFA.score` it solves the problem:

```
mat <- cem(treatment = "TXA", data = Le[,c("TXA", "Age", "Smooking", "HTN", 
                                            "Airway.diseases", "Malignancy", 
                                            "Bleeding.disorders", 
                                            "On.anticoagulants_antiplatelets", 
                                            "Required.ICU.admission", 
                                            "Classification.of.hemoptysis", 
                                            "Respiratory.support.", 
                                           "SOFA.score")], 
           keep.all=TRUE, baseline.group="1", 
           cutpoints=list(SOFA.score=c(0, 4.5, 9.5, 14.5, 19.5)))
```

But, it only matches one of the 11 cases:

```
mat$tab
#            G0 G1
# All       332 11
# Matched     1  1
# Unmatched 331 10
```

You'll probably need to adjust the cutpoints for the other variables (particularly the ones with lots of different levels) and maybe `SOFA.score` as well, to match more cases.

---

#### EDIT: use single variables

To loop through all of the variables you could do the following:

```
vars <- c("Age", "Smooking", "HTN", 
  "Airway.diseases", "Malignancy", 
  "Bleeding.disorders", 
  "On.anticoagulants_antiplatelets", 
  "Required.ICU.admission", 
  "Classification.of.hemoptysis", 
  "Respiratory.support.", 
  "SOFA.score")
out <- lapply(seq_along(vars), function(i){
  mtch <- cem(treatment = "TXA", data = Le[,c("TXA", vars[i])], 
           keep.all=TRUE, baseline.group="1", 
           cutpoints=list(SOFA.score=c(0, 4.5, 9.5, 14.5, 19.5)))
  Le[mtch$matched,  c("Record", "TXA", vars[i])]})
names(out) <- vars
```

The result is a list that contains the matched dataset for each variable.

Comment: DaveArmstrong Thanks brother, Now my question is, If I want to check the Match of TXA with each variable should I repeat this code with single variable or there is an another way to do it using loop one by one automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by check the match of `TXA` with each variable?  You could find the matrix of matches with `Le[mat$matched, ]`

Comment: I mean, if I want to check the match between Tax and Age, then I just need to remove all other variables in the code and just keep only these two variables in the code. Next with Sex and Tax and so on. So, I have to repeat the code multiple time. Is there any way which I can applied in the code to do this automatically using a loop. I hope you get my point .

Comment: You could, but each one of those would then only be matching on that single variable and none of the others.  I doubt that's what you want, or is it?

Comment: Yes I mean with single variable

Comment: Yes, I mean with a single variable.

Comment: @shakeelahmad Just edited the answer with a suggestion.